# Same function for few elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on my site alot of payment systems and instructions for them (visa, mastercard, amex and so..).

This script shows instructions when clicking on button.

```
$('#show-visa').click(function() {
    $('#instruction-visa').fadeIn();
});
$('#close-visa').click(function() {
    $('#instruction-visa').fadeOut();
});
```

I would need to duplicate this same script for every payment system, but there are many of them (aroung 20-25).. Writing same script for every payment system is not good idea. How can i do it better way?

Comment: Shouldn't we see the markup?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot see your markup, I will improvise...
Several things to note:

- I am using [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`
- Use a common class for toggle buttons and have one `.click()` handler for all of them
- Make use of [`data-*`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) in your markup

jQuery:

```
$('.toggle-option').click(function() {
    var $target = $(this).data('target'); // Get the data-target attribute
    $('#' + $target).fadeToggle();        // Toggle the id specified by data-target
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="toggle-option" data-target="visa">Toggle Visa</button>
<button class="toggle-option" data-target="mastercard">Toggle Mastercard</button>
<button class="toggle-option" data-target="maestro">Toggle Maestro</button>
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd2aU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the jquery prototype object. I created a simple jsfiddle for you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KenQ/M5m8g/1/)

```
$.fn.test = function(){
    alert('the id is: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to every single element and use the `data-` attribute to get the element which should be shown.
HTML

```
<button class="show" data-id="element1">Show</button>
<button class="hide" data-id="element1">Hide</button>
<button class="show" data-id="element2">Show</button>
<button class="hide" data-id="element2">Hide</button>
<div class="element" id="element1">Element1</div>
<div class="element" id="element2">Element2</div>
```

Js

```
$(function () {
    $(".show").click(function () {
       $("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn(); 
    });

    $(".hide").click(function () {
       $("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X96Ta/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have different selectors in your html structure for each payment system you could make an array with your payment system names and use $.each function on it to add handler for each one.

```
var paymentSystems = ['visa', 'mastercard', etc... ];
$.each(paymentSystems, function(name){
   $('#show-' + name).on('click', function() {
      $('#instruction-'+name).fadeIn();
   });

   $('#close-' + name).on('click', function() {
      $('#instruction-'+ name).fadeOut();
   });   
};
```